# Is there an R function for adding an index (numeric or character ID) column to large data frame by position of groups of values in blocks?

Tags: r

I have been trying to create code for adding specific indices to large data frames (on average  21000 rows divide into 400 blocks and 10 columns) by position of contigs ID in blocks. The blocks are given by position of a genomic ranges in genome. I was looking too for related topic on the Internet. I've not been able to creating/searching appropriate code for my problem.

**Example of data before indexing**

```
seqnames = sprintf("H7",seq(1:8))
start <- c(0,11,0,11,0,21,31,11)
end <- c(10,20,10,20,10,30,40,20)
strand <- sprintf("*", seq(1:8))
cont_ID <- c("001","001","004","004","003","001","001","003")
block <- c(seq(1:8))

df <- data.frame(seqnames,start,end,strand,block,cont_ID)

names(df) <- c("seqnames","start","end","strand","block","contig_ID")
```

```
   seqnames start end  strand  block  contig_ID
1       H7     0  10      *     1       001
2       H7    11  20      *     2       001
3       H7     0  10      *     3       004
4       H7    11  20      *     4       004
5       H7     0  10      *     5       003
6       H7    21  30      *     6       001
7       H7    31  40      *     7       001
8       H7    11  20      *     8       003
```

**Expected result**

Ideal index marks both connection of ID of contig to contigs with same ID (i.e. uses same value from contig_ID column) and  specific position of contig or group of contigs with same ID to another contigs in sequence of rows. The specific position is given by start and end columns. If values from start  columns is immediately subsequent to previous values from end column and are not separated by contigs with other ID, then this is "one block", which I need to mark by index. In example below I used for marking specific position/block combination of letters and ID of contigs.

data frame with desired indices (column index):

```
   seqnames start end strand block contig_ID  index
1       H7     0  10      *     1     001     A_001
2       H7    11  20      *     2     001     A_001
3       H7     0  10      *     3     004     A_004
4       H7    11  20      *     4     004     A_004
5       H7     0  10      *     5     003     A_003
6       H7    21  30      *     6     001     B_001
7       H7    31  40      *     7     001     B_001
8       H7    11  20      *     8     003     B_003
```

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Not very clear how you get `index`. Why does it become `B_xxx`?

Comment: Hi Jiri, please update your question how you would like to create your index, what determines if it is an A or B etc? (the other part of the index seems to stem from contig_ID).

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have added more detailed information about my problem. You will find them before example of my desired data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` you can do this:

```
library(data.table)

df <- as.data.table(data.frame(seqnames,start,end,strand,block,cont_ID))

sp <- split(df,f = cont_ID)

grouping <- function(x){

  x[, block_lag:= shift(block, fill = "lag")]
  x[is.na(block_lag), cumsum_block_lag:=1]
  x[!is.na(block_lag), cumsum_block_lag:=1+cumsum(block!=(block_lag+1))]
  x[, index:=paste0(LETTERS[cumsum_block_lag],"_",cont_ID)]
  x[, cumsum_block_lag:=NULL]
  x[, block_lag:=NULL]
}

index_sp <- rbindlist(lapply(sp, grouping))
index_sp <- index_sp[order(block)]


#   seqnames start end strand block cont_ID index
#1:       H7     0  10      *     1     001 A_001
#2:       H7    11  20      *     2     001 A_001
#3:       H7     0  10      *     3     004 A_004
#4:       H7    11  20      *     4     004 A_004
#5:       H7     0  10      *     5     003 A_003
#6:       H7    21  30      *     6     001 B_001
#7:       H7    31  40      *     7     001 B_001
#8:       H7    11  20      *     8     003 B_003
```

Comment: Many thanks LocoGris! You have saved my time. Now I can focus on next part of my work.